# How to recognize & escape apostrophe in sql search

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have sql query in my C# program to search or filter some records. When I pass a string value with apostrope, it throws some incorrect key word error in my C# program.

**My sample Input**

```
String Val= Tests of the 'convergence hypothesis' :  a critical note /  Daniel Cohen.
```

**My Query**

```
string MySqlQry="SELECT bc.BibId,
   stuff(
           (SELECT ' ' + bsc.NormValue + ''
            FROM BibContents bsc
            WHERE bsc.bibid = bc.bibid
              AND bsc.tagno = '245'
            ORDER BY bsc.Sfld
            FOR xml path(''), root('MyString'), TYPE).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') , 1, 1, '') AS Title,
   stuff(
           (SELECT ' ' + bsc.NormValue + ''
            FROM BibContents bsc
            WHERE bsc.bibid = bc.bibid
              AND bsc.tagno = '020'
            ORDER BY bsc.Sfld
            FOR xml path(''), root('MyString'), TYPE).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') , 1, 1, '') AS ISBN,
   stuff(
           (SELECT ' ' + bsc.NormValue + ''
            FROM BibContents bsc
            WHERE bsc.bibid = bc.bibid
              AND bsc.tagno = '250'
            ORDER BY bsc.Sfld
            FOR xml path(''), root('MyString'), TYPE).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') , 1, 1, '') AS Edition,
   stuff(
           (SELECT ' ' + bsc.NormValue + ''
            FROM BibContents bsc
            WHERE bsc.bibid = bc.bibid
              AND bsc.tagno = '260'
            ORDER BY bsc.Sfld
            FOR xml path(''), root('MyString'), TYPE).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') , 1, 1, '') AS Publisher,
   (SELECT top(1) Value FROM BibContents
   WHERE TagNo='100'
   AND Sfld='a'
   AND BibId=bc.BibId) AS Author
   FROM BibContents bc
   WHERE (bc.NormValue LIKE '" + Val + "%'
   OR bc.NormValue LIKE '% " + Val + "%')
   AND bc.TagNo='245'";

model = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<PoDetails>(MySqlQry).ToList();
```

Any help in providing the solution is appreciated.

Comment: The best solution is to use `SqlParameter` and prevent sql injection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148815/c-sharp-sqlparameters-short-hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply need to escape the single quote.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/

Before you insert 'Val' into the statement do:

Val = Val.Replace("'", "''");