# DateTime is not saving correct Date and Time in PHPMyadmin database field with"DateTime" data type

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, datetimepicker

I have DateTimePicker object in a C# winform application, from which I am getting date and time in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt` custom format. But whenever I save the data in phpmyadmin, it gets saved as `"0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000"` in the specific field. My code is bellow:-

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime scd = MydateTimePicker.Value;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into flight(flight_schedule) values ('" + scd + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# when you use a `DateTime` variable in a string context, it is treated as if it were appended with `.ToString()`.  Unfortunately that delivers a locale-specific rendering of the date. On my USA locale it looks like this:

```
 2/26/2016 7:12:19 PM
```

MySQL, when you present datetime values to it as strings, needs this format.

```
2016-02-26 19:12:19
```

In some versions of MySQL, a failure to interpret a date results in a zero date. Read this for more information on that topic.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates

Your insert query constructs a query string, so your `DateTime` value gets formatted in a way that MySQL cannot use. That's why you get that strange zero date.

If you changed your insert query to this, things would probably start to work.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into flight(flight_schedule) values ('" +
     scd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
```

Better yet, use parameters.  Read this for an example and discussion. [C# SqlParameters Short Hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148815/c-sharp-sqlparameters-short-hand)

Answer (score 1):

### No.

You have a [bad habit to kick as choosing wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You should *never* store your `DateTime` values as a `string`.

Change your `flight_schedule` to [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column type and pass your `DateTime` value *directly* with a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var cn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "insert into flight(flight_schedule) values (@date)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.Datetime).Value = MydateTimePicker.Value;
   // I assume you change your column type to Datetime
   cn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

EDIT:

Looks like you *already* have `DATETIME` column in your database, so my answer seems irrelevant but I [*still*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650810/datetime-is-not-saving-correct-date-and-time-in-phpmyadmin-database-field-withd#comment58984291_35650871) believe saving your DateTime as their values, not their string representations.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if it's productive to rebuke strangers for the habits you imagine them to have? Your solution to his problem is correct, but it's clear from his question that he's already using a `DATETIME` column in his table.

Comment: @OllieJones I simply missed that "with DateTime data type" part in title. Sorry about that. Your answer is completely explain the _root_ of the problem. `+1` for that. But still, I defend the "chosing wrong data type" term. If you have a `DateTime`, why on earth are you save it as a string? This will break consistency of your code and _might_ generate ambiguous situations if you try to parse _those_ strings to `DateTime` in future. Just my two cents.