# Adding quotes in a c# string?

Tags: c#, string

I'm having trouble adding quotes to a mySQL query string. I've took solutions from other people that seem to be working for them but it's not working for me.

What i'm trying:

```
 string sql3 = "SELECT wPrice FROM Vehicle WHERE VIN = \"" + (vehicleVIN) + "\"";
```

What i'm still getting :

```
        "SELECT wPrice FROM Vehicle WHERE VIN = \"58847722BRB\"
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: <strike>use single quotes:  '</strike>  Use SqlParameters and not string concattenation to create a sql-string to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Yes, *definitely* use parameterized SQL. Always. And be aware that when you look at a string in the debugger, it escapes it for you - your string *doesn't* have any backslashes in it.

Comment: No, strike that; use Entity Framework and stop writing SQL strings into your code!

Comment: Please see (for example) [SqlParameter used on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148815/c-sharp-sqlparameters-short-hand) this question how to construct a parameterized query.  - @CaiusJard _whisper_ Hibernate Hibernate

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Ill change it to use SqlParameters

Comment: And as a sidenote - if your database column is an "integer"-Type and you provide "an integer" as string it might still work BUT be slow as hell if you have lots of results due to autocasting string to int by sqlServer (provided string instead of int in a `where` condition - just a tale from bad experience)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never write SQL queries that use concatenated strings... use parameterized queries instead:

```
String query = "SELECT wPrice FROM Vehicle WHERE VIN = @vin";
String vin = "58847722BRB";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Prepare();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vin", vin);

    // ...
}
```

A [nice tutorial](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) for you.

Answer (score -2):

You only put one `"` character following a `\`, if you need two `"` characters you will need two `\` as in `\"\"`.

You could also use raw strings, which is a string introduced with an `@`:

```
string strExample = @"This is a ""raw string""";
```